# What is the best way to store images on a web app?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-mobile

I have been working on developing a web app that does basic CRUD operations and is connected to a MySQL database. I am using jQuery mobile and php.

Basically a user can send a report which contains some form data and their latitude and longitude from where they sent it, all of this is saved in the db. Now if they want to attach an image with the report, what would be the best way I could save these images in a db? Or should I be doing something else? Thanks!

Comment: Save them to disk, save the filename to the database.

Comment: save ur images on the application server..and store its server path in db

Comment: You dont "save" the image in the DB itself, you only store the path and the image file save it on disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the image should be sent to the server in post data that the server thens saves to a directory in the server good idea to also list the image src url in the database for quick retrival and use.